# Do the reference-collapsing rules apply to return type?

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference, type-deduction, forwarding-reference

The std::forward function template returns T&&. So in order to forward its argument as either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference, the return type of std::forward must be:

```
T&& if T is a non-reference type (T && == T&&)
T& if T is an lvalue reference type (T& && == T&)
```

What I mean is do std::forward's return type changes due to the reference-collapsing rules or the explanation is different?

Is the return type of std::forward a forwarding (universal) reference?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. The reference collapsing rules, as stated in [[dec.ref]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.ref#6), do not differentiate between the type of a variable, the type of a function parameter, or the return type of a function.

Comment: Thank you, but which exactly statement do you mean? The clause you refer to does't mention return type at all...

Comment: @beginpluses, the first paragraph in the link just talks about types. It does not say whether the rule applies to the type of a variable, the type of a function argument, or a return type. From that, I take it that the rule applies to to all types.